# Asking Question about Islamic history

Tags: discussion, support, questions

When we say Islam we generally speaking about era of Muhammad(SAW) but I want to ask if we can asks question about Islamic history on this site which effected current state of Islam as Religion.
Like

> cultural effects on islam?
>
> effect of certain victory or defeat on Islam?

And yes i know there is a History Site  of stack exchange but it don't cover topic in Islamic history.

Comment: i think no because everyone view history differently.

Comment: Islamic History would be on topic but when it is connected to politics etc. it wouldn't be . The critical point is what is called Islamic history and what is strange to Islam? As many things that came later in time (lets say for example after the 3rd Hijri century) are rather considered strange (from the view of Islam) and/or innovations.

Comment: Yes answered here https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/274/5383

Comment: Feel free to edit your post if what you have in mind is going in a different direction as the marked duplicate. I've just forgot for a moment my new privilege and marked it as such, forgetting that a mod voting implicates direct closure.

Comment: @Medi1Saif no it really a duplicate i just notice it

Comment: I not deleting it because it has been answered

Comment: i ask whether you want to re-open it to maybe get more answers, but for that we need a difference to the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression is that **Islamic history is on-topic** and I've not seen an alternative stance on this.  There's even a [history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag (with 240 questions currently).

Moreover, my experience suggests questions about Islamic history are reasonably well-received here.  Being historical, such questions tend to avoid the pitfalls when asking more personal question.

A similar meta question is [Islamic history, on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/274/17163)  The top answer writes:

> I don't see why Islamic history should be off-topic, unless it is about sectarianism, which is off-topic.
>
> As far as "history that involves Muslims" goes, I would have to give that a big X. This is a site about Islam, not Muslims. So, questions of any kind about Muslims are off-topic. -- [Dynamic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/282/17163)

As far as I know, this still applies.

So **the main catch is distinguishing *Islamic history* (on-topic) from *history which happens to involve Islam* (off-topic) and *history which involves Muslims* (off-topic)**.  I don't believe the community has clearly identified a boundary here; it's probably not worthwhile at this point, since we're not being inundated with borderline questions.

---

**Cultural effects on Islam**.  As long as it's primarily about Islam, it should be okay.  We need to understand culture to understand the Qur'an, ahadith, and the sunnah.

**Effects of a certain victory or defeat on Islam**.  Sounds on-topic; it's about Islam.  There's even some tags: [battle-of-karbala](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-of-karbala), [battle-of-jamal](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battle-of-jamal).

Comment: i will be difficult to explain new user about history.