# What is the meaning of those things I mentioned here on text?

Tags: discussion, support

There is a question I put and it shows me duplicate, what is that mean the word?

And on hold and protected. What is the meaning of those?

Answer (score 2):

Simply speaking our community tries to avoid some kinds of questions:

- Duplicates, asking the same question again and again is this is not productive. Note that duplicate also means that the answer for your question is included or covered in an answer of the duplicate post.
- Questions that are off-topic for some reasons: Cultural issues, dream interpretation, on politics (in Muslim countries) are some of these, beside any thing which is not related to Islam.
  See for example some related meta discussions:
  [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group)
  [Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language)
  [Should dream interpretation questions be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/780/should-dream-interpretation-questions-be-on-topic)
- Questions that are not well explained or lack necessary information, so that the reader needs to guess what is actually asked.
- too broad questions: questions that can't be clearly answered as there are too many aspects involved.
- opinion-based questions: one of the best examples are so called advice request, one my advise you to do this the other might advise you to do that.
  So a clear answer for the question doesn't exist.

This is due to the fact that we want focused and answerable questions instead of unclear, unspecific, too personal questions as our answers on the other hand  should be well elaborated, focused on answering the actual question and any claim to be supported by evidences.

So if a question is closed or put on hold then due to the fact that it is a question of one of the above kinds... this basically means that users (with enough reputation) of the community have voted to close it for some of the reasons and it passed a review queue.

Once it is put on hold or closed nobody is able to post an answer as long as the question was not edited/re-edited and passed a re-open vote queue. Note that in case of a duplicate, by editing you should also make clear why in your opinion your questions is not answered in the duplicate post!

Now to protecting questions this means a question can be protected from answers from new users -1 -10 rep (?)- (actually it is against spammers who create an account to bump in 
 the site and leave some spam or useless comments), this can AFAIK only be done by user with a high reputation and only after a prior spamming act.

All this can be found in our help center!

Answer (score 1):

### What does it mean for a question to be *closed*?

When a question is closed, no additional answers may be posted to it, although the question and existing answers can still be edited (by users with edit privileges or by suggested edit) and voted upon, and will continue to count for badges. The asker of a closed question may still accept an answer.

Closed questions can be re-opened by users who have sufficient reputation.

### What does it mean for a question to be *on hold*?

If a question has been closed (except as a duplicate), then for the first 5 days, it is marked as “on hold” rather than “closed”. This is meant to convey that the question requires improvement and may be reopened if improved. During this period, if the question [is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196026/nobody-in-my-community-has-the-power-to-re-open-a-question#comment618477_196026), it will be added to the [reopen queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). Other than this, there is no functional difference between “on hold” and “closed”.

### What does it mean for a question to be *marked as duplicate*?

Although these questions are not marked "on hold" for 5 days, they are still added to the reopen queue if they are edited within that time. Also, if there are pending votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate, the original poster can approve them and the Community user will instantly close it. Other than that, there are no functional differences between duplicate questions and questions closed for other reasons.

For more information on the duplicate close reason itself, see [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled).

### Who can close a question?

- Users with at least 250 rep may vote to close their own questions
- Users with at least 3,000 (500 on Beta sites) may vote to close any questions (see limits below)
- Moderators may close any question (regardless of their reputation) with a single vote
- Users who hold a gold badge for one of the question's tags may close as duplicate with a single vote
- If there are pending votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate of a certain target question, the question owner can *indirectly* bindingly close the question as a duplicate of that target (the Community user will cast the actual vote)
- The same users who can vote to close questions can also vote to reopen them
- Users can also [retract/cancel their close vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/915/) by clicking the close button again and clicking the "Retract Vote" button (you can't cast a close vote again on that question).

#### What are the limits for closing questions?

- Each user with vote to close privileges gets 24 votes to close per day (50 on Stack Overflow)
- 5 votes are required to close or reopen
- Votes will [expire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120896/why-do-close-votes-expire) if the question does not reach 5 votes
- Votes will expire if three users in review vote to leave open
- Questions with an open bounty cannot be closed
- You can only vote to close once per question, [unless your vote expired](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250453)
- You can only vote to reopen once per question, unless your vote expired
- You may not vote to close as duplicate if the other question is marked as a duplicate of the first
- Pending votes to close question A as a duplicate of B expire if B is closed as a duplicate of A

### What are the reasons for closing a question?

When closing a question, a reason must be provided for the action. Not all close reasons are available on all sites. If none of the reasons for closing the question apply, you should probably not vote to close.

Questions in these categories *may* be closed:

- [**Duplicate:**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) Questions that have already been asked and answered in the past should be closed. These serve as signposts to their previously answered duplicates. See [How to handle duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions)
- **Off-topic:** Questions are expected to be on-topic for the site to which they were posted, [within the scope defined by the community](https://stackoverflow.com/about).

  The “off-topic” option provides further guidance. Closers can either select a predefined message which will show in the close reason box, or type in a custom explanation which will be posted as a comment.

  - **Belongs on [another site]:** Questions that are off-topic on the site posted, but on-topic on another site in the Stack Exchange network. See [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)
- **Unclear what you're asking**: The way the question is currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what is being asked. The explanations in the question are not clear, or it is not clear what kind of answer is expected, or there is not enough information to solve the problem. The question may be reopened if it is clarified or if the missing information is provided.
- **Too broad**: The question must be edited to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer, and not ask multiple distinct questions at once.
- **Primarily opinion-based**: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

### Is closure the end of the road for a question?

Definitely not. Closed questions can and should be edited to improve them and address the reasons why they were closed in the first place. If you edit the question within five days of closure, it will be put into a queue for potential reopening. If you don't get around to editing it within five days, or others don't vote to reopen it in the queue, you should raise a meta question to bring it to everyone's attention so it can get more views that might translate into reopen votes.

It's only when a question can't be salvaged that it should move onto the next state - deletion.

### When are closed questions eligible for deletion?

Closed questions become eligible for deletion by the community after 48 hours, but users with 20K reputation or more are not subject to this restriction.  [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221) for the rules governing question deletion.  See also [Do closed questions ever get deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1867)

The Community user [automatically deletes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) closed questions in certain cases.

### I saw someone posting an answer to a question after it got closed.

The moment a question gets closed, only the GUI on the desktop site will prevent answering it. The server does not actually block answers to closed questions until 4 hours after it was closed, to prevent people from losing their work if the question gets closed while they're typing an answer.

The GUI limitation does not kick in on the mobile site or mobile apps if you load the question while it is still open, so it's also possible they posted the answer through those means within four hours of closure.

Comment: This answer is character-for-character identical to one from [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/351283).  Hmm...

Comment: Yes I copied from there