# What relevant tags could question 10790 have?

Tags: discussion, tag, tagging

What could be the relevant tag(s) for the question [What's the significance of placing one's right hand over the head after the prayer?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10790/3487) ?

I could only find one that is [clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification), it could have been [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat) but I wasn't sure. I could have made a new tag, but I couldn't come-up with something that was succinct enough.

[muslim-practices](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muslim-practices)? Wasn't convinced. Maybe because it didn't have a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say.  From the question, it appears that the most appropriate way to tag it is contingent on the answer to the question itself: Based on `Is this a manner of praying/supplication`, either [salat](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/salat) or [dua](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dua) would make perfect sense, but you obviously can't know which until *after* the question is answered.  Tagging with *both* "just in case" could potentially confuse the issue more.

[islamic-basis](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/islamic-basis) is a good fit; it easily falls under the definition of "Questions seeking to understand what, if any, Islamic basis a commonly-held practice or tradition actually has can be asked under this tag," even if it's clearly an Islamic practice (rather than [Folk Islam](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/656/22))

Beyond that, we would probably be better off if we had a tag encapsulating "Activities concomitant with *salat* but not actually part of the *salat* itself", but I'm honestly at a loss as to what to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Just clicked me. I suggest we have something like [identify-this-action](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-action) and [identify-this-practice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-practice).

This way if someone has a question about practice or action they have noticed they could put this tag on it and it'll be good to go.

It is the analogous to the [identify-this-movie](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) [on](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie) [Movies](http://movies.stackexchange.com).