# Is the "grave-worshipping" tag's wiki neutral?

Tags: discussion

Going through the [grave-worship](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-worship) tag's description I feel that it needs some overhauling. Even the tag itself is sort of controversial. A simple internet search of it would easily explain why.

The topic in itself is moot. And since the sites [What topics can I ask about here?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) states:

> For the purposes of this site, "Islam" includes all groups that
>   identify themselves as Muslim

greater care is definitely needed when writing it's wiki.

Should it be left the way it currently is? If not, what should be done about it?

Comment: I don't think the tag is worth keeping in the first place. It should be merged into a larger tag.

Answer (score 2):

The tag, as it stands, does not appear to be particularly useful.  The existing description is, at best, a definition of what "grave worship" *is*, but does nothing to define **[how or why the *tag* is supposed to be applied](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)**.

The very fact that the tag description explicitly defines it as a "prevalent [folk](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/656/22) practice" (rather than an "Islamic practice") suggests that such questions would be **blatantly *[off-topic](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/353/22)*** (as per [the FAQ](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), "Cultural practices and behaviour of Muslim communities"), so I question what use the tag even *has* on this site.

In many interpretations of Islam, there are practices that could easily fall under the general description (e.g. critics often lump *tawassul* as practiced by many Shi'ites and Sufis under the same term), and insofar as these practices would reasonably have an Islamic basis (so far as the site is concerned) they would be on-topic.  Such practitioners, however, **are unlikely to ever call it "grave worship"**, and as such are unlikely to ever use this particular tag for any reason.

If the only people for whom the tag would be on-topic won't ever *use* it, and the only people who would ever use it consider it by its nature *off-topic*, **exactly *who* then is the tag even *for*?**  The tag might be salvageable if its description could (or even tried to) reconcile this paradox, but right now it's just three different shades of useless.

Ergo, **I would recommend the tag be [burninated completely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/132874)**, and the questions using it reviewed to decide if there are better tags to apply, or if they even have any place on this site at all.

Answer (score -2):

I believe people here should be open to having discussions,Q/A and Dawaah to Qur'an and Sunnah and correct his/her Islaam.This way we would be portraying the right definition of Islam as per The Holy Qur'an and the sayings of the Prophet sallalahu alayhi wasallam.So the wiki description and the tag is good the way it is.

Comment: This site is not discussion, [chat] could be used for that, and definitely not for Dawaah/preaching and correcting someone's "Islaam". This is a site *about* Islam and not an *Islamic* site. Definition of Islam would tend to be variable as per your reasoning. "sayings of the Prophet" have varying degree of acceptance among different sects. [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/189/3487) and [Who can answer questions?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/101/3487). Plus highlight why the tag should be left as it is.