# (Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt

Tags: discussion

<sub>(This has plagued me for a long time now)</sub>

It's worries me to see that this site is condoning and catering questions like:

1. [urgently need advices for a divorce. I don't know how to convince my parents!](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10373/3487)
2. [how to practically unchain yourself from sins?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10362/3487)
3. [Is divorce the best solution for my problem](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10202/3487)
4. [How to help husband change?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10257/3487)

that are primarily seeking advice, under the guise of Islam.

Should this  site be used as a, religious, [agony aunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_column)?

Answer (score 5):

These question, way I see it, come under the category of [*religious/spiritual prescriptions*](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853)/**Plz email me teh codez.**

The problem I see in allowing these type of questions, which can come under *primarily opinion-based*, is that less effort is put into constructing the core question and more is put into discussing and describing one's *personal* problems in order to draw advice ([counseling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counseling_topics)) on those issues, and users as a *religious duty*, not seeing whether it is appropriate on this site, would *advise* them.

Such questions should be put on-hold and/or closed if the core Islam-related *question*, provided there is one, is quite trivial and/or doesn't reflect effort.<sup>Not being apathetic</sup>

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the other answers here and the way the site is currently operating, the community and mods are making an either/or decision:

- If a non-trivial, core Islam-related question can be discerned **leave open**
- If not **close**

I propose that the guidelines are changed, in the interests of more clearly steering the site away from the "(Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt" feel it appears to have.

These are the guidelines I propose:

- If a non-trivial, core Islam-related question can be discerned, and any personal details are not in your face, **leave open**
- If a non-trivial, core Islam-related question can be discerned, and personal details are in your face, **close/edit/reopen** (or just edit but don't leave them lying around as asked), downplaying or removing the personal aspects. As goldPseudo [puts it](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/624/3208):

  > Any social problems abstracted out enough to ask "What should a Muslim do in this situation?" are probably fine.

  As a specific, [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10125/3208) contains a non-trivial, core Islam-related question but ***has far too much personal information*** (and angst) that ***should be edited out***:

  [image]
- If no non-trivial, core Islam-related question can be discerned, **close**
- if a counseling question looks anything like [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/17331/please-please-please-read-this-and-suggest-me-about-my-relation), ***delete*** (or flag and ask a mod to delete it):

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a fine line here. Most questions along these lines are intensely specific and require actual counselling. As such, they are closed (as far as I've seen at least; some may have slipped through the cracks). Some others can be made general, and those we leave open. After all, tazkiyah *is* a core part of Islam.

Comment: "About" tazkiyah would be okay. *"How/what should I do?"*. I'm afraid, way I see it, with that we'll have our first casualty i.e. of *objectivity*.

Comment: @BleedingFingers My point was that some "What should I do" questions can be rephrased as "What can a Muslim do in such-and-such situation"