# Can we open question about Nikkah?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13329/nikkah-related-hadiths was closed as not clear. I think it is an important question and needs to be answered. Basically the question is asking about doing Nikkah of a girl without the consent of her parents. I think it perfectly eligible question. I have researched on this subject and would like to answer it.

If it is not being opened, may I ask what it is not clear about it or why it is not a good fit for the site?

Comment: As i have edited the question from urdu to english i believe it was a valid question. The person who asked wants to know can she do nikah and she requires an answer according to her situtation i would like it be re opened

Answer (score 2):

In abstract, questions about Nikkah are perfectly fine as far as I can tell. What isn't so fine on our religion sites is asking for ["personal guidance in response to practical questions"](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi). On *this site* these questions have been labeled [(Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/islamic-counseling-and-agony-aunt).

In this particular case, the question doesn't have nearly enough detail to be able to responsibly answer. The three things the OP told us are:

1. She's 17.
2. She's in need of [Nikkah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam).
3. Her parents won't let her.

I don't know much about the topic of Islamic marriages, but reading the Wikipedia page convinces me that many, *many* more things must be known about the OP's situation in order to provide useful help. At the very least, we'd need to know why here father has rejected the marriage since "the contract of an Islamic marriage is concluded between the guardian (wali) of the bride and bridegroom, not between bridegroom and bride." ([According to Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Islam)) I suspect that even a mullah who knows her family well would have a difficult time answering wisely. Why would we, who know so very little about her, agree to give her advice?

Perhaps just as importantly, a question on Islam.SE should be "one for the ages". That is to say, if the question could be rephrased to be helpful to all sorts of people in the future, it will be much more useful. Asked in the abstract, the question might be useful and interesting; in this specific instance, leaving it open is taking a gamble.

Comment: the question is very clear IMO. The girl is in love with someone, her father does not agree. She wants to marry him. Can she marry him? This is a common situation in our societies. You exactly pointed out the answer. The girl's guardian (Wali) has to consent the marriage, otherwise the marriage is not valid. This is exactly the answer she is looking for. We have to be careful. By proving too much detail in the question, the question becomes too localized and not useful anymore. This is just my opinion.