# Can we improve moderation?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation, quality-control

I have argued in the past either in chat or on meta that we have a couple of issues with moderation here. I am writing here once again in hope of improving it.

**Problem 1 - Ego Issue**

I asked this question on meta ([question about Nikkah be opened](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/can-we-open-question-about-nikkah)). Before posting it on meta, I raised it in chat but were ask by a mod to post it on meta if I think it should be opened. So I did but got no answer.

My take on closing this question is this: It was correctly put on hold by the moderator first because the question was asked in a non-English language. Totally correct. Then someone translated it to English and now the question made perfect sense. Now I wanted this question to be opened so I can answer it but the mod who closed it would not open it and would not answer my question on meta why it can't be opened or what is it is not a good fit for the site. I think ego comes into play as in almost all cases. If a moderator closes the question, he would not open it. He considers it as his insult. I have seen the mod asking me to post the same question *again* because he would not open a close question. It all seems ego to me.

**Problem 2 - Other moderators won't step in**

Now assuming that this one moderator won't open the question for whatever reason, he does not really own that question. Other moderators simply won't interfere and address the issue as if it would offend his brother moderator. This type of approach will kill the quality of this site. Remembers our moderators are here to improve quality of the site but this approach actually ruin it because we are making our personnel relations on top over the quality of this site.

So my question is, is my assessment correct or wrong that we have ego problem and other moderators do not step in to fix an issue even if it may make sense to them? Is there an SE policy in generally where moderator don't touch each other questions? So basically if one mode closes something, the other mod is not supposed to open it even if accordion to him it is valid question and should be opened. What is guidelines of SE in this case?

Comment: Please take a note of this [Hadith](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/13) and remove hate words like that in heading #1

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under a fundamental misunderstanding of exactly what it is moderators are expected to do around here.

The Stack Exchange model is built around the idea of *community* moderation.  That means that it is the *community* who is expected to keep questions open, to decide what does and does not belong on the site, and generally to keep the site clean.

For the most part, all the diamond moderators do is accelerate that, especially in a site's early days when there is little to no actual *community* moderation going on.  But beyond that, we are users like any other, and our voice is as much part of the "community" as anyone else's.

If we see a question that we feel needs to be closed, we'll vote to close it.  If we see a post that we feel needs to be deleted, we'll vote to delete it.  If we see a question that shows no research effort or is not useful, we'll vote it down.  This is exactly the same as any other user who has earned enough reputation; just because our votes are more binding doesn't mean they don't come from the community like any other.

We also handle flags raised *by* the community to ensure that things run smoothly.

If you, personally, disagree with other users (moderator or otherwise) about whatever action has been taken, that's fine.  But then it's *your* responsibility to sway the community to your point of view.  That is what meta is for.

If you posted a question to meta and it got little to no response, that's not the fault of the users who chose not to answer it.  You attempted to sway community opinion, and you failed.  There's nobody to blame here, that's just a side-effect of dealing with other people; other people are under no obligation to agree with you just because you want them to.

If moderators seem exasperated when they're expected to do everything around here, that's not an ego problem.  That's a natural response to constantly being told to do something that shouldn't even be their job, while the rest of the community whose job it actually *is* does nothing.

So, to answer your actual question of "Can we improve moderation?":  Yes.  Please do.  Get the community to actually do its job so that we diamond moderators don't need to step in.  All we want to do is build a site that we can be proud of, so if you don't want us swinging the diamond hammer at every little problem we see, it is incumbent on *the rest of the community* to ensure that these problems can be solved without us.

Comment: I am not saying moderators are abusing their power. My point is there is a probably poor judgment, sectarianism that I have seen. When other moderators are just silent when one mod decision is controversial, it is a problem and very *non-constructive* by the other moderators. A moderator should not be that sensitive. He is suppose to be the most mature player among us who would not get offended so easily.

Comment: @muslim1 If a moderator shows poor judgement, so be it; people make mistakes.  If you want to show that they are actually acting against *community* opinion, then demonstrate through meta what that *community* opinion actually is.  Given how poorly received most of your recent meta posts have been, there's no evidence that your claims reflect the community at all.

Answer (score 3):

The moderation can definitely improve but let me proclaim that we *do* have good committed moderators in the site. But the question is: is that enough or are they the only ones to be held responsible? Answer is a definite negative! Because as rightly pointed out by goldPseudo, moderation is a collective job. Moderators are only there to help the site in its fledgling steps and help us learn by example, but they don't claim perfection either.

Having said that, I do find faults with some moderators' decisions every now and then, and I have done voice my protests strongly on some case, but again, as said by goldPseudo, we can't expect perfection. Part of the reason is that moderators just like everyone else may be influenced by their personal attitudes, preferences and prejudices, and often so without even realizing. But that's a very human thing. Also realize that in this site, we have only a handful of relatively committed users other than the mods, and that's a big defect. If we have a large enough community of committed and conscientious users, possible moderators' faults will also be corrected by collective moderation of the site.

All that said, I give a good, grateful mark to the mods. Without them this site might have been closed down by the StackExchange admins long ago!

Comment: so you would agree, the two issues I highlighted are non issues?

Comment: @muslim1, they might or might not! But the thing is there's no solution, unless your objections can be reasonably discussed and accepted by the community! The existing community (however weak or strong it is as of yet) apparently doesn't agree with you!

Comment: I do not have support as such but an overwhelming amount of minority sects post have been deleted here. I have quote examples where they will not re-open closed questions. They will not investigate the biased moderation, I thing they did look into it but found no good reasons. The problem that they have not seen, there is no one standard. If Sunni posts are subjected to same criteria as shia posts, I am sure a tone should be deleted.

Comment: @Agreed, but notice that bias is often unconscious. Everyone is naturally inclined to posts that are in line in his own beliefs. Mods are not exceptions. But as I said there's no other way around but to have a balanced community.