# Why do I get this message on Stack Exchange Islam?

Tags: discussion

Why do I get this message of Islam Stack Exchange "We are no longer accepting questions from this account"? How will be like this and what should I do in order to about this message?

Comment: If I delete what is unclear then I can send questions again,right?Coz I don't find anything unclear coz the rest was edited and made be clear and what's next?I don't what I can do.

Answer (score 4):

This is explained on the [question ban](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) help page.  Question bans happens when people post poorly received questions.

> How can I get out of a question ban?
>
> Begin by improving your existing questions: do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions which were poorly received.

---

Since you seem to want to know how to improve your questions, let's go through the latest 10 questions one by one (don't read this if you're not comfortable with blunt, negative feedback).  The two biggest issues: 1. not one of these questions shows research effort, 2. repeatedly, very little effort is put into making the question readable, and other users have edited your posts (wasting their time).

1. [Can I make the same supplication and to pray to Allah in English even if I know Arabic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43425/can-i-make-the-same-supplication-and-to-pray-to-allah-in-english-even-if-i-know) (score: 0)  [closed as too broad]

   I edited this one the other day, and I think it's okay now.  Nevertheless, it could be improved by showing research effort.

   However, there's a clear question which could be answered by someone knowledgeable.  There's motivation behind the question, but it's not overly personal nor way too much unimportant detail.  Unfortunately, it's closed.
2. [What should I do in order to see a angel or my angels or to see if Allah Has agreed with someone's idea or wish?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/what-should-i-do-in-order-to-see-a-angel-or-my-angels-or-to-see-if-allah-has-agr) (score: -1)

   Here's the body of the text:

   > I would like to know what should I do or if there any Supplication to say so that I can see and angel?Coz I want to discuss with him and stuff,what should I do in order to see a Angel?And it is ok if I ask God Almighty to send someone tell me if He is agreed with my wish or idea?like a Angel?Because I have made a Supplication and I don't know if it is ok,and does not include no haram and only permissible thing and also to be good in it,and I would like to know if He is agreed and send also exceptions after it,I would be extremely happy if it happens like this,is it ok?

   I look at this and think *it's a waste of my time reading this* and move on to the next question.  It's an unformatted "wall of text" peppered with spelling, grammar, and punctuation errors.  If it were an important question, the author would have put more effort into presenting it.

   After reading it, I found that it was a waste of my time.  Simply find the question you want to ask and make that stand out (and present it well).  Most of this question is not needed, but a reasonable amount of motivation doesn't hurt.

   It also lacks: (a) what you already know e.g. by searching the web [research effort], and (b) why you think you are capable of seeing angels.

   It also needs appropriate tags (e.g. [malaikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaikah)).
3. [How can I stop commiting a disbelief and shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43401/how-can-i-stop-commiting-a-disbelief-and-shirk) (score: -1)  [closed as primarily opinion-based]

   I'd give up on this question.  We're not here to solve your personal problems.

   But if you want to attempt to salvage it: (a) get rid of the stuff about you, (b) phrase it more academically, e.g. "What measures can a person adopt to stop committing shirk and disbelief?" (c) show your research (e.g. what you get if you Google the question).
4. [If a 15- to 16-year old became knowledgeable of Islam but refused to enter, if they die will they enter Heaven?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43394/if-a-15-to-16-year-old-became-knowledgeable-of-islam-but-refused-to-enter-if-t) (score: 1)

   This could be improved by showing research effort (e.g. what you get if you Google the question).
5. [Can a person drink with limits the beer with alcohol?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43392/can-a-person-drink-with-limits-the-beer-with-alcohol) (score: 0) [closed as duplicate]

   Identifying duplicates is one of the reasons we show our research effort.  Simply putting "alcohol" into the search bar gives multiple questions along these lines.

   If you read these answers and this doesn't fully resolve your question, you can rephrase your question to this more specific unresolved question, identifying why the prior answers don't address your question.
6. [If I forgive those who hurt me, will Allah answer my supplication fast?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43390/if-i-forgive-those-who-hurt-me-will-allah-answer-my-supplication-fast) (score: 0)

   No research effort.
7. [Is it true that exaggerating love will lead you to shirk?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43376/is-it-true-that-exaggerating-love-will-lead-you-to-shirk) (score: 1)

   > I was wonder that exagerrating love will lead you to shirk?I mean Christians love Jesus Christ(pbuh)then slowly by slowly they made him as a god because of too much love,is it true?

   No research effort.  No reference to back up your claim about Christians.  No motivation.  Spelling, grammar, and punctuation errors.
8. [Is there any Supplication that will make other person to forget about the mistake I did?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43373/is-there-any-supplication-that-will-make-other-person-to-forget-about-the-mistak) (score: -1)

   Another *I know reading this will be a waste of my time* question body:

   > I want to know if there is a dua in Quran that when for example I have made or said a silly thing that is unforgettable in from of the kafirs and I felt ashamed of my self and for sure this is unforgettable and there is a supplication so that I can use it so that other people will forget completely just like never happened and what ever I try to remind them,they will not be able never-ever,coz there are things I said by mistake in front of the kafirs and are very shameful it is not about religion and in past yes it was only one time,coz I would like from them to forget about what I said or done silly things completely just like never happened.Is there any supplication in Quran just as I mentioned on text?

   The title is "Is there any Supplication that will make other person to forget about the mistake I did?"  (a) Why would anyone other than you care?  That's the problem of some random person on the internet.  (b) This indicates a request for personal advice, which is off topic.  (c) This is not Men in Black.

   No research effort.
9. [Is what I mentioned here on text is a disbelief?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43367/is-what-i-mentioned-here-on-text-is-a-disbelief) (score: 0)

   Again, another user has had to waste their time editing your question.

   (a) It's still a very long question, more of a Where's Wally (Where's Waldo) than a question. [From a reader's perspective, it's like watching a bad movie hoping it will get better, but it doesn't.]  (b) It's a question about you and your personal problems, not a question about Islam.
10. [Can a person lie to keep something safe or hidden or to protect something which will benefit him?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43352/can-a-person-lie-to-keep-something-safe-or-hidden-or-to-protect-something-which) (score: 1)

    This time two users have had to waste their time fixing your question.  If your question was actually important, it would be worthwhile taking the time to format it properly in the first place (and not rely on others, wasting their time).

    No research effort.

---

Also note, these questions have useless titles:

- [about things being written for you](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43248/17163)
- [about the prayers](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43272/17163)
- [Put a name to your child](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43294/17163)
- [Seeking help of someone](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43311/17163)
- [about the will of Allah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43319/17163)

See: [Advice for writing question titles on Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1837/17163)

Comment: What should I do if I wiped out the unclear questions and are remained only the clear questions but still I can't ask?

Comment: The questions are turned from unclear to clear.And still I get the message:We are no longer accepting questions from this account.What should I do next?

Comment: So what?I only asked for me to learn

Comment: I thought in here I can ask anything,and even if I do ask about"my personal problems"why would that be wrong?It is just for me to learn more.And I'm trying to improve my questions and grammar and etc..

Comment: See [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group) and [(Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/islamic-counseling-and-agony-aunt).

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones And in your question B)"Why do think you are capable to see angels"?.God Almighty said in Quran that He is capable of all things and for Him there is no such thing hard,everything is easy for Him and if He wants He can make me be able to see angels,but if He does not want for me to see,then I'll not be able to see.If you don't believe me,check out in Quran and tell me ifI'm right or not.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones And your question from a)Why would anyone other then you care about this?The answer is because there are some who will remember about my mistake and they'll make a joke about this and I'll feel bad after this

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones And one thing,if you said there are some questions that are no research effort and the question are edited,then I shall delete?How how?