# Should the question "Intolerance in muslims" (17080) be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Should the question [Intolerance in muslims](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17080) be closed for being a question on

> Muslim culture or behaviour unrelated to the teachings of Islam [..]. See: [Islam SE: Not an Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-an-muslim-peer-support-group).

?